When Jesus said it's better to enter the kingdom of heaven with one eye, does that mean such injuries won't be healed in the resurrection?
I do believe that the righteous dead who are having physical disabilities such as being unable to walk, see, hear  or talk will be raised whole in the resurrection of the saints which will be the first one. Jesus taught that they will enter into life with their disabilities
Mathew 18:9

would be better to enter the kingdom of heaven with one eye than to have two eyes and be thrown into the lake of fire

Jesus healed these people while he was here on earth, why can't he raise them whole in the resurrection of the saints?

The issue here is not about healing. It's about the world being a stumbling block to others including Christians. Matthew 18:7, "Woe to the world because of its stumbling blocks! For it is inevitable that stumbling blocks come; but woe to that man through whom the stumbling block comes!"
At vs8, hand and foot speak of actions or behavior. In contrast, the "eye" at vs9 is a symbol of desire or covetousness. Jesus is using figurative language, especially hyperbole; (deliberate overstatement or exaggeration to illustrate a point).
In order to avoid self-destruction and becoming a stumbling block to others, believers must be willing to give up what they selfishly want to do or what they selfishly desire. Ultimately, Jesus is saying (vs8) "it is better for you to enter life ("Life" refers to the life of the coming age, everlasting life) crippled or lame, than having two hands, or two feet, to be cast into eternal fire."

Well explained, are you a unitarian ?

@SoFewAgainstSoMany Thank you for the thumbs up. Now, why are you asking me if I'm a Unitarian? And what type of Unitarian are you? Universalists type, Biblical Unitarian, Socinian that denies the deity of Jesus Christ? No, I'm a "Trinitarian" all the way through. Btw, we did agree on some points when we were discussing issues with JsWitness, a Jehovah's Witness this past week.

Bond, okay. I believe that Jesus is light of Genesis that God called out of darkness because John says that light was in the world and the world knew it not , even Christians

@SoFewAgainstSoMany I have to disagree with you as Jesus being the light of Genesis. I base this on John 1:4-9. Vs4, In Him was life, and the life was THE LIGHT OF MEN. Vs5, And the light shines in darkness, and darkness did not comprehend it." What beautiful words that Jesus lights up men's hearts by believing in Him. Vs, John the Baptist bears witness of the light/Jesus Christ. Vs9, Jesus is the true light that enlightens every man. At Malachi 1:3, John the Baptist clears the way of the Lord who will suddenly come to HIS TEMPLE and we will delight in Him. Who do you think this is referring?

I believe it was referring to Jesus, other Christians believe that light to be the physical light but the physical light comes from the sun which was created onnthe fourth day, so this original light on the first day had to be spiritual and the Bible breaks our silence on the light of all lights.

I like this answer better than my own attempt (which I've now deleted).

I like this response - well done Mr.Bond. We agree on this one :-)
